# Two way relation for UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, parent-child

I have a container view controller say ContainerViewController and another UIViewController(PhotoViewcController) which i am adding as a childviewcontroller in ContainerViewController. So that message is forwarded from ContainerViewController to PhotoViewcController. But how can i use the two way relation in the parent child view controllers? so that message is passed form PhotoViewcController to ContainerViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a property in child class like this

```
@property (assign) id pDelegate;
```

and synthesize it, and when you go to child view controller, set the delegate as self before push/present as

```
childController.pDelegate = self;
```

now when you want to send the message, do this

```
if([self.pDelegate respndsToSelector:@selector(popedBackFromChild:)])
{
 [self.pDelegate popedBackFromChild:<some object>];
}
```

tell me if you need further explanation

Comment: If in my containerViewController i add a UIScrollView as a subview an i want to add the child view controller's view as a subview to scrollview do i have to add the line [self addChildViewController:childViewcontroller] ? In this case will the parent of the childViewController will be the ContainerViewController?

Comment: the same thing, when you initialize child object set it's delegate to parent, preferred way is to make an initializer and set delegate there received as parameter

Comment: @TheSaad Thanks for *if([self.pDelegate respndsToSelector:@selector(popedBackFromChild:)])* didn't know that.

Comment: this saves us from app to occur crash

Comment: So should i add the ImageViewControllers view directly as subview to scrollview without adding as a child to the containerViewContoller?

Comment: that depends on tasks in child view, preferred way is to make an object as property in parentclass and add

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that you can do this. Either define a protocol for it in the child class and define it in the parent class or you can post and notification and pass the necessary information as a dictionary. As @The Saad has told you, this is the best way you can define a protocol but notifications are easier to manage.
P.S. Parent class is the class where you will update the information and Child class will be providing it.